# How to tell which properties of an odata EntityType are required?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, odata

I am looking at https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata and I am wondering how one can determine whether a property of an EntityType is required.

There are a few property facets listed [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part3-csdl/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part3-csdl-complete.html#_Toc453752528), but none of them seem to indicate whether a property must have a value.

Is what I am asking for simply not part of the spec?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Nullable` attribute is used to specify whether a value is required. Kindly check out section **7.2.1 Nullable** (under **7 Structural Property** - v4.01) of the spec http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-csdl-xml/v4.01/csprd02/odata-csdl-xml-v4.01-csprd02.html#_Toc486522905

Comment: Hi, 

you are right, it just seems that Microsoft does not use the Nullable attribute consistently, i.e., there are many API calls where the Nullable attribute is unset (and thus defaults to true) and yet, API calls fail if one omits properties for which with Nullable is set to true.

Additionally, they also seem to indicate property requirements for some methods via annotations:

```
<Annotations Target=“microsoft.graph.user/accountEnabled”>
    <Annotation Bool=“true” Term=“Microsoft.Graph.Validator.Required”/>
   ...

</Annotations>
```